# Does Dynamic Programming paradigm always focus to bound the runtime complexity within O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a confusion about the runtime complexity of dynamic programming.Is this will always be O(n) if I use dynamic programming paradigm to solve a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

There are counter examples. For instance there is a [dynamic programming algorithm for the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in-advance_algorithm) which is NP-complete and thus no *O(n)* algorithm can exist.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Dynamic programming is only about storing and **reusing** partial solutions (solutions of sub-problems) already calculated.

This approach is independent from how hard it is to find these partial solutions or how hard it is to create a new partial solution out of other partial solutions.

So you cannot say that dynamic programming restricts the complexity of an algorithm at all.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming